# How to start a process by another group using sudo

Tags: sudo

I wanted to start one process as a non root user with a group (non-root) by `sudo`.
I added the line below in `/etc/sudoers`

```
xyz ALL =  (xyz:abc) NOPASSWD: <cmd>
```

But I am always getting the error below,

```
Sorry, user xyz is not allowed to execute '<cmd>' as xyz:abc on SC-1.
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo -l`?

Answer (score 0):

You want the group to have root permissions or only one user?

If you want only one user, add this to the sudoers file, after User privilege specification `root  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`:

```
xyz ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

`xyz` being the user. This always works for me (remember to log out and in)

If you want an entire group to gain root permission I can't help you.